# Using webpack with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs, webpack

I have created this nodejs script that require phantomjs to access the DOM :

```
var phantom = require('phantom');
phantom.create(function(ph) {
    ph.createPage(function(page) {
        page.open("editor3.html", function(status) {
            console.log("opened diagram? ", status);
            page.evaluate(function() {
                return document.getElementById("GraphImage").src;
            }, function(result) {
                console.log(result)
                ph.exit();
            });
        });
    });
},{
    dnodeOpts : {
        weak : false
    }
});
```

And i'm trying to use **webpack** to get javascript code, but when i'm runnig this command :

```
webpack ./entry.js bundle.js
```

I get this error :

[image: errorRunningWebpack]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error when using webpack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34495818/error-when-using-webpack)

Comment: Did you figure it out? It looks like you should run Phantom as a child_process of Node, since PhantomJS isn't a node module & webpack doesn't recognize the phantomjs modules.